# Joomla Mysql query in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I'm trying to build a simple select list in Joomla 2.5 with php and mysql, but I've got a problem: it doesen't load the options name... are there any error?

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('optValue');
$query->from('#__sobipro_field_option');
$query->where("fid='38'");
$db->setQuery((string)$query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($results){
echo "<select>";
 foreach($results as $result){
    foreach($result as $value) {
    $query->select('sValue');
    $query->from('#__sobipro_language');
    $query->where("fid='38' and language='it-IT' and sKey='".$value."'");
    $db->setQuery((string)$query);
    $name = $db->loadResult();
    echo "<option value=\"$value\">".$name."</option>";
    }
    }

    echo "</select>";
}
else {
echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors from the query? I would definitely think about reconstructing your query first as foreach result that you get, you're running another query.

Comment: Can't understand what are you meaning.
I don't take any error, the two queries works fine alone, but combined retrieve a select list with blank options...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you're trying to debug Joomla! code turn on debug mode (`Global Configuration->System->Debug Settings`) and turn Error Reporting up to `Development` (`Global Configuration->Server->Error Reporting`), then you would have seen your problem straight away.

1. `$query` is a actually an object of type `JDatabaseQuery` and should be used as is in the `$db->setQuery($query)` call without casting to a `(string)`.
2. When referencing a database, table or column name it's a good idea to use Joomla's mechanism for wrapping the name is the correct quotes e.g.
   `$query-select($db->quoteName('optValue'))`
   Amongst other things this will insure that SQL keywords aren't a problem.
3. Likewise for values, use the Joomla! provided `$db->quote()` method. e.g.
   `$query->where($db->quoteName('fid') . '=' . $db->quote('38'));`
4. When building a `WHERE` query with multiple values `AND`ed together you can simply add each item as it's own `->where()` clause.

So your where before I would tend to write as:

```php
  $query->where($db->quoteName('fid') . '=' . $db->quote('38'));
  $query->where($db->quoteName('language') . '=' . $db->quote('it-IT'));
  $query->where($db->quoteName('sKey') . '=' . $db->quote($value));
```

Finally, as you've said both of your `$queries` work by themselves, but when put together in your code as shown they don't.

The reason for this is that after you configure `$query` for your first statement (and run it), you continue to add to the second statement to the *original `$query` object*. So, that when you do the second, third etc `setQuery($query)` the SQL is getting longer and longer and unlikely to return any results.

As you don't test for success of each `$db->loadResult()` in the inner-most `foreach` loop you never see the error.

At the very least you need to add a new `$db->getQuery(true)` at the beginning of your inner loop, like this:

```php
<?php
// Get default database object
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

// Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Build the query
$query->select($db->quoteName('optValue'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__sobipro_field_option'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('fid') .'=' . $db->quote('38'));

// Set the query for the DB oject to execute
$db->setQuery($query);

// Get the DB object to load the results as a list of objects
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($results){
    echo "<select>";
     foreach($results as $result)
     {
        foreach($result as $value)
        {
            // Get a new query object
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            // Build the query
            $query->select($db->quoteName('sValue'));
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__sobipro_language'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('fid') .'=' . $db->quote('38'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('language') .'=' . $db->quote('it-IT'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('sKey') .'=' . $db->quote($value));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $name = $db->loadResult();
            echo "<option value=\"$value\">$name</option>";
        }
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
else
{
    echo 'Error';
}
```

This is going to potentially create a lot of objects, so, you should consider if there's a way to restructure it all into one SQL query this will make it significantly faster and reduce the load on your server.

Comment: Oh yeah!
It works like a charm!!!
I agree with you when you suggest me to restructure this script, but for now I'll use it. I'm at the beginning with php and mysql, so it is the best solution i can write at the moment.
Thank you very much!